# address from metamask behaving weirdly in a function call

Tags: metamask

On my frontend, I am calling a function that requests users to sign into their metamask and retrieve the address of their account:

```
  const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
    method: "eth_requestAccounts",
  });
```

However, it returns the address in all-lower-case form. I know that transactions will still pass but I want the address to be identical to the one in metamask. Is there any way to fetch it?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the address with ethersjs function

```
const currentAccount = await ethers.utils.getAddress(accounts[0])
```

it will return the right address identical with metamask
see https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/address/#utils-getAddress